# How to remove user SessionScoped?

Tags: session, jsf-2

I try to do log out function in JSF 2.0. First I give AUTH_KEY for logging user. After log out I remove this user's AUTH_KEY.
My problem is not working log out for the user session that don't remove.

Section of login function:

```
if (startupInfo.getConnectionId().equals("success")) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                            .getSessionMap()
                            .put(AUTH_KEY, loggedUserInfo.getUserId());
                    return "success";
                }
```

Logout

```
    public String logout() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove(AUTH_KEY);

    return "logout";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should invalidate the HTTP session in your logout method. Removing the user info only doesn't kill the session:

```java
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                        .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
  session.invalidate();
}
```